# How to use the reduce function on a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, reduce

I have this this list of tuple:

```
  a = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]
```

I would like to use the reduce function in order to get this result:

```
  (3, 12)
```

I tried:

```
  x = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)
```

But i get an error...I want to add up all the elements in the first index of each tuple, then add up the second element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the output of a `reduce` to be a tuple, all the intermediate results should also be a tuple.

```
a = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]
print reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), a)
```

**Output**

```
(3, 12)
```

**Edit:** If you want to get `(0, 0)` when the list is empty

```
a = []
print reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), [(0, 0)] + a)
```

**Output**

```
(0, 0)
```

**Edit 2:** Reduce accepts [default initializer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) as the last parameter, which is optional. By using that, the code becomes

```
a = []
print reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), a, (0, 0))
```

Comment: How would I make it if I have an empty list and I use this reduce function that it would give me the result (0,0) ?  Right now, it is giving me an error that int object is not subscriptable

Comment: I made list 'a' an empty list, so a = [] then I would return the reduce function you have just written. However, I would get an error after that.

Comment: `reduce` accept optional `initializer`: `reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), a, (0, 0))`

Comment: @falsetru Edited my answer to include that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]
>>> map(sum, zip(*a))
[3, 12]
```

**UPDATE**

According to Raymond Hettinger,

> zip-star trick abuses the stack to expensively compute a transpose.

Here's an alternative that does not use list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]
>>> [sum(item[i] for item in a) for i in range(2)] # 2 == len(a[0])
[3, 12]
>>> a = []
>>> [sum(item[i] for item in a) for i in range(2)] # 2 == len(a[0])
[0, 0]
```

Comment: Or as a tuple `tuple(map(sum, zip(*a)))`

Comment: Though pretty, this really isn't a good way to solve the problem.  It doesn't scale well (the zip-star trick abuses the stack to expensively compute a transpose that isn't really necessary to solve the problem).

Comment: @RaymondHettinger, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer with your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You were close.  Just modify your code to unpack the input tuples first.  Once you add the new values, just repack the result tuple:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)]
>>> reduce(lambda (sx, sy), (x, y): (sx+x, sy+y), a)
(3, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
>>> from numpy import asarray
>>> a = asarray([(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6)])
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, a)
array([ 3, 12])
```